# How to use django-smart-select

Tags: django

Let's say I have the following model:

`class Location(models.Model)
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)`

I need to create a dependent dropdown so that when I select a continent I get all countries belonging to that continent. How should I do it?

Answer (score 8):

Have you read [the documentation](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#chained-selects)? It's pretty straightforward. Depends on how you've got your continent/country set up. I'd recommend something like [django-cities-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light), which provides you with tables populated with countries/regions. I don't think it has continents though.

If you don't want to do that, you need to set up a Country model that has a column for Continent ID for example:

```
Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
```

Then in the Location model set the fields thus:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey 

Location(models.Model):
    newcontinent = models.ForeignKey(Continent) 
    newcountry = ChainedForeignKey(
        Country, # the model where you're populating your countries from
        chained_field="newcontinent", # the field on your own model that this field links to 
        chained_model_field="continent", # the field on Country that corresponds to newcontinent
        show_all=False, # only shows the countries that correspond to the selected continent in newcontinent
    )
```

From the docs:

> This example asumes that the Country Model has a continent = ForeignKey(Continent) field.
>
> The chained field is the field on the same model the field should be chained too.
> The chained model field is the field of the chained model that corresponds to the model linked too by the chained field.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

1. **pip install django-smart-selects**
2. **Add smart_selects to your INSTALLED_APPS**
3. Bind the smart_selects urls into your project's urls.py. This is
   needed for the Chained Selects and Chained ManyToMany Selects. For
   example
4. Your Models
   [Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Tzi.jpg)
5. Index.html
   [Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvfr8.jpg)