# django-filter chained select

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using django-filters lib https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html. I need to make chained select dropdown in my filters.
I knew how to make it with simple django-forms like here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html.
When user pick region, i need to show cities in this region? Have someone idea or solution how to build filters like this?

Answer (score 0):

Integrate [django-smart-selects](https://pypi.org/project/django-smart-selects/) with how you perform the filtering.

> This package allows you to quickly filter or group “chained” models by adding a custom foreign key or many to many field to your models. This will use an AJAX query to load only the applicable chained objects.

In analogy to the original question for `Region -> City`, the [documentation's example](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#chained-selects) is `Continent -> Country` which fits exactly to what is needed.

> Once you select a continent, if you want only the countries on that continent to be available, you can use a `ChainedForeignKey` on the Location model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = ChainedForeignKey(
        Country,
        chained_field="continent",  # Location.continent
        chained_model_field="continent",  # Country.continent
        show_all=False,  # only the filtered results should be shown
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
```

Related question:

- [How to use django-smart-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460078/how-to-use-django-smart-select)